# Need how to inherit a dictionary class with template type

Tags: c#, dictionary

I got hanged with the problem. I have a class which will inherit dictionary.But dictionary should be of template type. I got succeeded till inheriting a dictionary class to a class. But am not getting how make derived dictionary as a template. Please help in this.
Please get my code below.

```
public class MGDDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<string,string>
    {
        public MGDDictionary()
        {

        }

        public static SelectedOption value { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return EntitySerializer.ObjToString<MGDDictionary<TKey, TValue>>(serializer, this);
        }
        public static MGDDictionary<TKey, TValue> FromString(string objectStream)
        {
            return EntitySerializer.FromString<MGDDictionary<TKey,TValue>>(serializer,objectStream);
        }
    }
```

In the above code I need  this line to be of a class which inherits dictionary with a template in it.

`public class MGDDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<string,string>`

Many more Thanks in advance

Comment: Keep your personal data at your profile

Comment: I think code is not clearly published. please get it here below: 
public class MGDDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey,IEnumerable<TKey>> where TKey:MGDDictionary<TKey,TValue>
    {
       public MGDDictionary()
        {}
       
       
        
    }

Comment: Will `MGDDictionary` be of a specific type, like `string, string`, or do you need it to be generic?

Comment: I need it to be of generic type which will inherit a dictionary template

Comment: So don't make it inherit from `Dictionary<string,string>`, but from `public class MGDDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`

Answer (score 2):

It makes no sense for your class to be generic. I think you can just change it to remove the type parameters:

```
public class MGDDictionary : Dictionary<string,string>
{
    public MGDDictionary()
    {

    }

    public static SelectedOption value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return EntitySerializer.ObjToString<MGDDictionary>(serializer, this);
    }
    public static MGDDictionary FromString(string objectStream)
    {
        return EntitySerializer.FromString<MGDDictionary>(serializer,objectStream);
    }
}
```

On the other hand, creating your own collection classes is rarely a good idea. Prefer composition over inheritance, in general.

Also note that a *static* property called `value` is almost certainly a bad idea, both in the name and the staticness...

Comment: hi andre, thanks for your response. But as per our requirement, the Dictionary<string,string> has to be reframed as a Dictonary with template model, where I strucked to do so. Can you help me here

Comment: @user1617198: Sorry, I don't understand your comment, or your requirements.

Comment: @ Jon- thanks for your response. My requirement is that I need to define a class which inherit a dictionary template

Comment: @user1617198: That's far from detailed, and it's still unclear why you feel your class should be generic. If you've limited the key and value types to be string, what use would the type parameters have?

Comment: Ok BUt can anyone suggest example of a dictionary with template , and how it looks like.